# ROWTYPE declaration throws ORA-16000 error in standby database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following pl/sql:

```sql
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select log_mode, open_mode, database_role from v$database;

LOG_MODE     OPEN_MODE            DATABASE_ROLE
------------ -------------------- ----------------
ARCHIVELOG   READ ONLY WITH APPLY PHYSICAL STANDBY

SQL> DECLARE
  tst_row  dual%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
END;
/
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-16000: database or pluggable database open for read-only access
```

Could somebody explain why I get **ORA-16000** here?

Comment: I don't have a read-only instance to test this but I believe the issue is that `dbms_output` internally tries to write to a buffer which isn't going to be allowed in a read-only database.

Comment: No. The root cause is in %ROWTYPE. When I use `tst_col dual.DUMMY%TYPE;` declaration all fine.

Comment: You can get rid of the error by explicitly running `set transaction read only;`

Comment: It does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this question was answered [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=rowtype-declaration-throws-ora-16000-error-in-standby-database).

> Looks like a bug. We try to compile the type definition and temporarily store it in a table (which of course is not permitted)
>
> Reproduced in 18 and 19 as well. Even if using temporary undo or a global temporary table, you'll still get it.
>
> I've got some more info for you. Assuming you are planning on doing some "real" work, ie, DML etc...then you can redirect your anonymous block to the primary, for example:

```sql
SQL> DECLARE
  2    tst_row  dual%ROWTYPE;
  3  BEGIN
  4    null;
  5  END;
  6  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-16000: database or pluggable database open for read-only access

SQL> alter session enable adg_redirect_plsql;

Session altered.

SQL> DECLARE
  2    tst_row  dual%ROWTYPE;
  3  BEGIN
  4    null;
  5  END;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But unfortunately the `ADG_REDIRECT_PLSQL` command was introduced only in Oracle 19c. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sbydb/data-guard-concepts-and-administration.pdf).

> **10.2.2.2 Running Top-level PL/SQL Operations on Active Data Guard Standby Databases**
>
> Top-level PL/SQL blocks that you run on Active Data Guard standby databases can be redirected to and run on the primary database, if they do not contain bind variables.
>
> To redirect top-level PL/SQL operations that are run on a standby to the primary, configure automatic redirection using the following command on the standby database:

```
  ALTER SESSION ENABLE ADG_REDIRECT_PLSQL;
```

> You can configure automatic redirection for top-level PL/SQL operations only at the session level.